# Loading online OSM raster tiles using URL in custom QGIS application (C++)

Tags: qgis, raster, openstreetmap, tiles, c++

I am trying to write a C++ version of a custom QGIS (v 3.10) application I initially wrote in Python that overlays data onto OpenStreetMap.  I am able to do this successfully by loading online tiles via URL as a raster layer in Python using WMS provider; however the same URL does not work when using the C++ API, despite being able to load other raster files (e.g. GeoTIFF).

Code in Python:

```
url = 'type=xyz&url=https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org'
url += '/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857'
prj = QgsProject()
qmc = QgsMapCanvas()
layers = []
ras = QgsRasterLayer(url,'OpenStreetMap','wms')

if ras.isValid():
    print("Basemap loaded successfully!")
    prj.instance().addMapLayer(ras)
    qmc.setExtent(ras.extent())
    layers.append(ras)
    qmc.setLayers(layers)

 else:
     print("Unable to load basemap.")
```

C++ version:

```
QString url = "type=xyz&url=https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org";
url.append("/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857");
QgsProject() *prj = new QgsProject();
QgsMapCanvas *qmc = new QgsMapCanvas();
QList <QgsMapLayer *> layers;
QgsRasterLayer *ras = new QgsRasterLayer(url,'OpenStreetMap','wms');

if ( ras.isValid() )
{
    qDebug() << "Basemap loaded successfully!";
    prj->instance()->addMapLayer(ras);
    qmc->setExtent(ras->extent());
    layers.append(ras);
    qmc->setLayers(layers);
 } else
{
     qDebug() << "Unable to load basemap.";
 }
```

I get the successful message and loaded map in Python and the invalid message and no map in C++. I have tried using other URL's but nothing has worked thus far.  If there are plugins available that might help, but I would still need to write workable code without the use of the QGIS gui itself (as in most examples using plugins).

**EDIT** Using the advice of @ThomasG77 below, I made the following amendment:

```
QStringList plist = QgsProviderRegistry::instance()->providerList();
for ( int i=0; i<plist.length(); i++ )
{
    cout << plist.at(i).toStdString() << endl;
 }
```

which yields the following output:

```
gdal; memory; mesh_memory; ogr
```

Do I have to manually add the OSM/WSM provider in my .pro file or environmental variable?  Using Fedora Linux (31)

Comment: What are your loaded providers in your standalone Python, in your C++? In PyQGIS, within QGIS, I do `QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()` to check. How fo you load your Python standalone project and your C++, in particular env variables? Providers are maybe not "well" loaded.

Comment: Well the qgis libraries/headers are added to my .pro file for the C++ standalone and I have them added to my .bashrc (using Fedora) in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.

Comment: @ThomasG77 see my edit for the output of the C++ equivalent using QgsProvderRegistry

Comment: About "OSM/WSM provider in my .pro file or environmental variable". Just try and retest again your `QgsProviderRegistry` again to see if it changes the list and also if behaviour for loading layers has changed too.

Comment: Nothing has changed.  The Python QgsProviderRegistry shows essentially all drivers: ['DB2', 'WFS', 'arcgisfeatureserver', 'arcgismapserver', 'delimitedtext', 'gdal', 'geonode', 'gpx', 'grass', 'grassraster', 'mdal', 'memory', 'mesh_memory', 'mssql', 'ogr', 'ows', 'postgres', 'spatialite', 'virtual', 'wcs', 'wms'].  Both have the same .bashrc/.bash_profile environment settings.  Only difference is I have python library/plugin paths added to the PyQGIS app paths.

Comment: What does GDB do within `QgsRasterLayer` when loading the class when doing step by step debug? I consider you made a debug mode build in CMake. PS: do not know the details how (not C/C++ dev) but know it's possible e.g https://github.com/lucernae/qgis-debug-mode

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/79549/load-osm-tiles-using-url-in-custom-qgis-application-c

Comment: Hi I have this problem too, I could load TMS,4 years ago by the way you said but now I got `QObject::connect(QgsNetworkAccessManager, Unknown): invalid nullptr parameter
QObject::connect(QgsNetworkAccessManager, QgsNetworkAccessManager): invalid nullptr parameter` Error!! could you find a solution?